# Restoring form from LocalStorage when page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="filterSection in filterSections">
    <h4>{{ filterSection.title }}</h4>
    <div class="checkbox" ng-click="loaderStart()" ng-if="filterSection.control == 'checkbox'" ng-repeat="option in filterSection.options">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchParameters[filterSection.key][option.key]" value="{{ option.key }}" checked><span></span> {{ option.value }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can access it with 
`$scope.searchParameters`.

I can store it using 
`localStorage.setItem('search', JSON.stringify(cleanedParameters));`

I can access store with 
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("search"));`

But I have no idea how could I restore it when page refresh. Is there some function or example of directive which I could use? I couldn't really find anything similar to my problem.

Comment: Why this one is not working ? `localStorage.getItem("search")`

Comment: I can access it. But I dont know how to put it into scope and generate it on my screen so all checkboxes are "checked". I'd need to put it in some kind of loop...

Comment: are you storing an array of data or what type ?

Comment: Key: search Value: ["43","47"] from Chrome resources.

Comment: And those are id's of boxes which are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can just inject this straight back into $scope without much effort. This solution works just fine: `$scope.searchParameters=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("search"));`

I was trying to parse whole thing by myself, but it was not worth effort :)

With `$scope.$watch('searchParameters', function (newValue, oldValue)` I check if element has changed and I update it in LocalStorage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LocalStorageService module of angularJs.

for more detail please check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage

Comment: But I dont have problem with storing data. I have problem with putting that data into my form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as shown below.Just create an array and push the values into that.Then you can access that array values as you wish through a loop.

```
var a = [];
a.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ngStorage (to abstract away all the JSON parse stuff) - http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage

Then anywhere (in my controllers, directives, services), I inject the `$localStorage` provider, and load the storage into the `$scope`:

```
app.controller("FooCtrl", ["$scope", "$localStorage", function($scope, $localStorage){

   $scope.storageStuff = $localStorage.somethingSavedInStorage;

}]);
```

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2997/

Comment: And if you inject it  straight to scope, it show changes on the screen? I tried putting whole thing into `$scope.searchParameters=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("search"));` but it didn't really work. I need just to check some boxes in array if condition of existing in local storage is true. But dunno how to do it.